# JSP/javabean/servlet MVC

Tags: java, design-patterns, jsp, servlets

Where should mysql code go in terms of MVC? Obviously not the view.

Answer (score 6):

It's not part of MVC. It should go in a DAO class which is (in)directly called by C.

#### See also:

- [Design patterns in Java web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)
- [Basic DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 4):

It should be in one separate layer. which your service layer should be calling from Controller(Servlet)

**Also See**

- [DAO design pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html)